# MySQL Returns wrong values on SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

All,

I'm wondering if this is a MySQL bug, but since I've seen others playing with larger numbers than this, I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong here.

Here is my table structure for the table I'm querying:

`mysql> describe ipspace6\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************

  Field: id

   Type: decimal(39,0) unsigned

   Null: NO

    Key: 

Default: NULL

  Extra: 

*************************** 2. row ***************************

  Field: addr

   Type: decimal(39,0) unsigned

   Null: NO

    Key: PRI

Default: 0

  Extra: 

*************************** 3. row ***************************

  Field: netmask

   Type: decimal(39,0) unsigned

   Null: NO

    Key: 

Default: 0

  Extra: 

*************************** 4. row ***************************

  Field: subnet

   Type: int(4)

   Null: NO

    Key: 

Default: NULL

  Extra:`

Now, I run a simple SELECT statement against the "id" column:

`mysql> SELECT id FROM ipspace6 WHERE id='50552019118453823914642686339427860480';

+----------------------------------------+

| id                                     |

+----------------------------------------+

| 50552019118453823730175245602332344320 | 

| 50552019118453823730175245602332344320 | 

| 50552019118453823914642686339427860480 | 

| 50552019118453823914642686339427860480 | 

+----------------------------------------+`

...What the heck is going on here? Two of these results are valid, and two definitely are not.

It's not like I'm doing some super-complex nested query or anything, this is simple stuff, and it's driving me insane.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes. When you operate with any kind of numerics you should always use numbers, not strings.

Comment: +1, can reproduce problem with quotes, no problem without. Probably casting string to integer instead of decimal for comparison.

Comment: Accepted answer, this is exactly what was wrong. I had no idea that MySQL would do that with single-quotes. Thanks!

Comment: >> Probably casting string to integer instead of decimal for comparison --- actually mysql is trying to cast the field to the expression it compared to, not vice versa. That's why `id` = '42' (where `id` is an integer) can often be the cause of the performance degradation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try passing "id" not as a string but as a numeric value?

Comment: i was across internet searching why my query didnt work, it was the casting, i was sending numbers as strings