# MySQL SELECT Statement not working when executed from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following piece of code, executing a pretty simple MySQL query:

```
$netnestquery = 'SELECT (`nested`+1) AS `nest` FROM `ipspace6` WHERE `id`<='.$adaddr.' AND `subnet`<='.$postmask.' AND `type`="net" AND `addr` NOT IN(SELECT `id` FROM `ipspace6` WHERE `addr`<'.$adaddr.' AND `type`="broadcast") ORDER BY `id`,`subnet` DESC LIMIT 1';

$netnestresults = mysql_query($netnestquery);
$netnestrow = mysql_fetch_array($netnestresults);
$nestlvl = $netnestrow['nest'];

echo '<br> NESTQ: '.$netnestquery;
```

Now, when I execute this in PHP, I get no results; an empty query. However, when I copy and paste the query echoed by my code (for debug purposes) into the mysql command line, I get a valid result:

```
mysql> SELECT (`nested` + 1) AS `nest` FROM `ipspace6` WHERE `id`<=50552019054038629283648959286463168512 AND `subnet`<=36 AND `type`='net' AND `addr` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `ipspace6` WHERE `addr`<50552019054038629283648959286463168512 AND `type`='broadcast') ORDER BY `id`,`subnet` DESC LIMIT 1;
+------+
| nest |
+------+
|    1 | 
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't put quotes around my variables, as then MySQL will try to evaluate the variable as a string, when it is, in fact, a very large decimal. I think I might just be making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't tell where.

Comment: Single / double quote difference? html-tags tag you can't see in the browsers output fouling up the query?

Comment: Stupid mistake #1: not using a parameterized query.

Comment: All,

I solved my problem by re-writing my query a different way, which PHP and MySQL seem to like. I'm giving Jordan the accepted answer as he was the most active and tried to help. Thanks, all!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it. Can you post what you had to do, for the sake of history and the children?

Comment: Mistake #2: Using the mysql_ functions.  Mistake #3, freaking huge numbers in PHP as anything but a string...

Comment: Charles, is there a better way to interact with MySQL without the built-in functions in PHP? I'm trying to develop an IPv6 web app for keeping track of subnetting and aggregation, and storing these numbers as strings makes MySQL freak out.

Comment: Jordan, Here's my new query. Not too different, but it seems to work:$netnestquery = 'SELECT `subnet`, (`nested`+1) AS `nest` FROM `ipspace6` WHERE `id`<='.$adaddr.' AND `subnet`<='.$postmask.' AND `type`="net" AND `subnet` NOT IN(SELECT `subnet` FROM `ipspace6` WHERE `addr`<='.$adaddr.' AND `type`="broadcast" AND `subnet`>='.$postmask.') ORDER BY `id`,`subnet` DESC LIMIT 1';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify the line to say $netnestresults = mysql_query($netnestquery) or die(mysql_error());

It may be giving you an unknown error, such as a bad connection, missing DB, etc.

Comment: Hi Jordan,

Thanks for your response. I've tried that, and I get no errors whatsoever. However, when I do this:

$netnestrow = mysql_fetch_array($netnestresults) or die(mysql_error());

I get a blank page.

Comment: Are you able to select anything from the DB? Maybe could you do "Select nested as nest From ipspace6 Limit 0, 1" to see if anything comes back?

Comment: Jordan,

Yes that works fine, I get a valid result when I run that query.

Comment: For giggles, can you change the query to this:
"SELECT (nested+1) AS nest FROM ipspace6 WHERE id <=$adaddr AND subnet<=$postmask AND type='net' AND addr NOT IN(SELECT id FROM ipspace6 WHERE addr<$adaddr AND type='broadcast') ORDER BY id, subnet DESC LIMIT 1";

Comment: I tried your new query, and I still don't get any results from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

do an `echo $netnestquery`
before calling `mysql_query`
also add a die(mysql_error()) there.

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE `id`<=50552019054038629283648959286463168512

That's a pretty big number there.

PHP has issues with big numbers.  The maximum size of an integer depends on how PHP was compiled, and if it's on a 64-bit system.

Have you checked that the variable containing that number hasn't been capped to a 32-bit or 64-bit integer?  If it has been capped, you're going to need to take steps to make sure it's only being stored as a string in PHP.  MySQL accepts strings that are entirely numeric as numbers without complaining.

(That being said, I'm not sure that MySQL can do anything with a number larger than 64-bits.  The largest integer column is `BIGINT`, which is 64-bits.  There's also `NUMERIC`, but it's treated as a floating point number, and that might not be what you want to do...)

Comment: Charles,

I'm storing these numbers in a Decmial(39,0) UNSIGNED column. It seems to work just fine, but I ran into issues with MySQL trying to interpret these numbers as strings. See my other question (regarding exactly this) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993828/mysql-returns-wrong-values-on-select-statement